# Algorithm: make loop lines appear below the words

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I am using the `algorithm` environment and I do not know how to make the lines for the loops under the corresponding word, not where I have them now.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\SetKwInOut{Parameters}{Parameters}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[htb]
    \DontPrintSemicolon 
    \justifying 
    \caption{The caption}
    \KwData{Some data}
    \Parameters{a,b}
    \KwResult{Result}
    \For{something or other}{
        This is some random text \;
        Some more text\;    
    }   
    More text here
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I am getting the following:

[image]

How can I fix the problem? I want the line to appear right under `for`.

Thanks, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `\justifying` from within the `algorithm` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\SetKwInOut{Parameters}{Parameters}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[htb]
  \DontPrintSemicolon 
  \caption{An algorithm}
  \KwData{Some data}
  \Parameters{$a, b$}
  \KwResult{Result}
  \For{something or other}{
    This is some random text\;
    Some more text\;    
  }   
  More text here
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I need something to keep the lines justified as I have some long lines, how would one do that?

Comment: @PereGarauBurguera: If you have a long line, you can place it inside a `[t]`op-aligned `\parbox` of appropriate width (`\linewidth` minus the indentation) within which you can place the text (it should naturally be justified). [Here is an example](https://pastebin.com/raw/gWghWWaD) ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWx9x.png)).

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!